# SharePoint Authentication using Webclient

Tags: c#, sharepoint, webclient

I'm a rookie in C# & .NET and currently developing a Broken Links Tool for a pretty big company. The main point in the application is checking there Intranet SharePoint sites.

A few weeks ago I made a proof of concept. I used a WebRequest to get the status of a current page and set the credentials with

```
   httpReq.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Nowadays I have to use a WebClient for the connection and in the same way it doesn't work anymore.

I also tried

```
Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials,
```

and

```
Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username,password, "domain"),
```

as well

```
webclient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Why it doesn't work with the webclient?

Comment: What type of authentication does the SharePoint server use? You may run into issues if it's using Claims-based authentication or something other than NTLM.

Comment: It's NTLM using the Windows Credentials

Answer (score 1):

Is your certificate valid?
In any case, add:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; }
```